# doc file created in iPhone documents encoding issue

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to write a MSword file in document directory by the following code:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* path;
NSString* gradeDoc = [self fetchCommentsDesc];
NSString* str = [self.objStudent.strName stringByAppendingFormat:@".doc"];
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
[gradeDoc writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[self fetchCommentsDesc] returns NSString.
self.student.strName is a String
```

Issue:
When i Open the doc file created in document directory of iphone, all the special characters in the doc appears as boxes or some arabic chars.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You're writing some UTF-8 bytes, which is not a ".doc". Try writing it to a ".txt" file.

Also, you may have to write a "byte order mark" for some text editors to notice that it's UTF-8 or UTF-16 (in NS/CF-land, this is known as an "external representation"):

```
NSData * d = [(id)CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(NULL, (CFStringRef)gradeDoc, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, 0) autorelease];
[d writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Also try kCFStringEncodingUnicode and kCFStringEncodingUTF16.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but that didn't work.
Writing into a .txt file is not an issue but client want .doc file.
i tried the above code, when we try to open the .doc file msword opens the file conversion dialog box which has a list of encodings from which i have to select 1. This same dialog box used to appear when i tried this:
[gradeDoc writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];

Comment: Try outputting HTML as a ".doc". It's a nasty hack (and you might need to use <meta> or XML entities), but I think most versions of Word support it.

Comment: I tried this, .doc is now getting opened perfectly in ms word but not getting opened in "pages" in mac and "good reader" in ipad.